# How to solve this integral of trigonometric f in Mathematica

Tags: integration, mathematica

How to solve this integral in *Mathematica*

Is it possible to solve it numerically?

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 \cos\big(&(.75-.75x^2)\cdot y_1 
+ (.25 - .5x - .75x^2) \cdot y_2 \\
+ &(-.5x + .5x^3) \cdot y_3 + (.125 - .75 x^2 + 0.625 x^4) \cdot y_4 
\big) dx
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please put some effort into making the question readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is No.
You can't have undefined symbols/variables in numerical integrals.

---

If you want a purely numerical solution, you could make a 4-dimensional grid that covers the range of $y_i$ that you're interested in, do the integrals at those points and interpolate between the results.
Or, more simply, just define a numerical integral function that you can call when ever you need the result (it's a simple integral, so it is quite fast).

```
nInt[y1_?NumericQ, y2_?NumericQ, y3_?NumericQ, y4_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Cos[(.75 - .75 x^2) y1 + (.25 - .5 x - .75 x^2) y2
    + (-.5 x + .5 x^3) y3 + (.125 - .75 x^2 + 0.625 x^4) y4], 
   {x, -1, 1}]
```

You can then plot any section of the 4D function that you want. For example and no particular reason,

```
Plot[nInt[x, 2 x, 0, 1], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: screenshot]

---

More interesting (to me) is how far you can get with this integral analytically.
If you didn't have any $x^3$ or $x^4$ terms, then integral can be done completely in terms of Fresnel C and S functions ([W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BCos%5Ba%20%2b%20b%20x%20%2b%20c%20x%5E2%5D,%20%7Bx,%20-1,%201%7D%5D)).

```
Sqrt[2c/Pi] Integrate[Cos[a + b x + c x^2], {x, -1, 1}]//TraditionalForm
```

[image: screenshot]

In general, it is a little more tricky. You could try a series expansion:

```
sc = Simplify[SeriesCoefficient[
  Cos[a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + e x^4], {x, 0, n}], n >= 0]

(* Integrate term by term. Sum can't be done by Mma *)
(*Sum[(1+(-1)^n)/(1+n) sc, {n, 0, Infinity}]*) 

(* but can expand up to any order *)
Table[(1 + (-1)^n)/(1 + n) sc, {n, 0, 10}] // ExpToTrig // 
  Simplify[#, Trig -> False] &
```

The [SeriesCoefficient](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SeriesCoefficient.html) returns a [DifferenceRoot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DifferenceRoot.html) expression - i.e., it can't be given in "closed form".  *Mathematica* is then unable to compute the commented out `Sum`. However, you can get the expansion of the result to any order, the `Table` command returns

```
{2 Cos[a], 0, 1/3 (-b^2 Cos[a] - 2 c Sin[a]), 0, ...
```

If you think about `a` being dimensionless, `b` having dimension one, ..., `e` having dimension 4, then each term is of a fixed dimension. Note that odd terms in the series vanish (because of the symmetry of the integral).

This result can then be specialized to your particular values, e.g.,
`a = .75 y1 + .25 y2 + .125 y4`, etc...

Comment: I must try Simon. Really, answer is professional, better 100 times then my question.